# Please tell me why the scroll view doesn't work in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollview

I am trying to do a checklist in android studio. But I don't pretty sure if I use the `scrollView` correctly. Right now the text which I wanna move to the next page pile up one the first one on the top of the phone.(1)

Please tell me how to do.
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

(1):Screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox9Mc.jpg

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Battery"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox2"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox2" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Standby Power"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox4" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Parking Brake"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fire Warning System"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EXT Test Switch"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Forward Fuel Pump"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox6" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="APU"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="start"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="APU Generatars"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox10" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox9"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox9" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YAW Damper"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox12"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox12" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox15"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox13"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox13" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Galley"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox15"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Emergency Exit Lights"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox11"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox11"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox11" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox17"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox18"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox16"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox16" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Smoking"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="on"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox19"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollView can have only on root element inside it, so what you can do is have on linear layout inside scrollview and than populate rest inside Linearlayout

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Battery"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="on"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox2"
   android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox2" />
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="off"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Standby Power"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="on"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox4" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="off"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Parking Brake"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="test"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:checked="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fire Warning System"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="test"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:checked="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="EXT Test Switch"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="test"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox7"
    android:checked="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Left Forward Fuel Pump"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="on"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox6" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="off"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="APU"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="start"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:checked="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="APU Generatars"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="on"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox10"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox10" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="off"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox9"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox9" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YAW Damper"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox12"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="on"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox14"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox12"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox12" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="off"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox15"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox14"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox13"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox13" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Galley"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox14"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="on"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox14"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox14"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox14" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="off"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox16"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox15"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Emergency Exit Lights"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox11"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox11"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox11" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="on"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox17"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="off"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox18"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox16"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox16" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No Smoking"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="false"
android:text="on"
android:id="@+id/checkBox19"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: don't forget to give orientation="vertical" to linear layout

Comment: Ummm.....

May I ask one more question...
I followed your instruction to do. And then the app still can't scroll in the simulator.
One problem it shows is on the first line
<RelativeLayout  and it shows that "Start tag has wrong closing tag."

What should I do ..?

Comment: I need to ask another question ??

Comment: Right here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492075/why-the-scroll-view-did-not-work-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

and if there are more than one, Wrap the Views inside of a LinearLayout/Relative Layout/Frame layout whichever you are comfortable with so the ScrollView has only the LinearLayout as a direct child.