# Why the Scroll View did not work in android studio?

Tags: android, scrollview

I am doing a checklist. But the scroll view didn't work. When I tried to export, I couldn't either.
 One error it shows is right on [1]. And the picture [2] is the code on the top.

Thanks :)

1:https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOHWD.jpg

2:https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmEPP.jpg

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Battery"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox2" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Standby Power"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox4" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Parking Brake"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fire Warning System"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EXT Test Switch"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Forward Fuel Pump"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox6" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="APU"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="start"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="APU Generatars"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox10" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox9"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox9" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YAW Damper"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox12"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox12" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox15"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox13"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox13" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Galley"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox14"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox14" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox15"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Emergency Exit Lights"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox11"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox11"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox11" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox17"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="off"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox18"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox16"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox16" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Smoking"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="on"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox19"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: "One error it shows is right on [1]" -- Your opening tag is `<RelativeLayout>`. The corresponding closing tag is `</ScrollView>`. These do not match.

Comment: So I should change </ScrollView> into </RelativeLayout>, right?

Comment: wait i will edit in some time and post it as well

Comment: "So I should change </ScrollView> into </RelativeLayout>, right?" -- you need them to match. Which one you change depends on whether you want a `RelativeLayout` or a `ScrollView`.

Comment: @MarkChen, as  CommonsWare mentioned what you have to do, i apprently  answered  using LinearLayout which can be done using RelativeLayout, it's just choose prefrence but you should try to learn how XML works that should help you :)

Comment: I hope I can understand how it work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
 >


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Battery"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="on"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="off"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Standby Power"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="on"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox4" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="off"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Parking Brake"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="test"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:checked="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fire Warning System"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="test"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:checked="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EXT Test Switch"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="test"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox7"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox7"
            android:checked="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left Forward Fuel Pump"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="on"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox6" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="off"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="APU"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="start"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:checked="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="APU Generatars"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="on"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox12"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox10"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox10" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="off"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox9"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox9" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="YAW Damper"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox12"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="on"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox14"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox12"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox12" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="off"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox15"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox14"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox13"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox13" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Galley"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox14"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="on"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox11"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox14"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox14"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox14" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="off"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox16"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox15"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Emergency Exit Lights"
            android:id="@+id/textV_iew12"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox11"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox11"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox11" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="on"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox17"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="off"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox18"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox16"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox16" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No Smoking"
            android:id="@+id/textView12_"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="on"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox19"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView12" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i have edited it again, just copy it and paste it to your layout